# The ability to select ALL potential options in a Shiny input along with a dynamic table

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shinyapps

I have the following code below that allows for three different "phases" of selection, each input dependent on the one before. Right now the code exists like this:

```
  ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Test Dashboard "),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("data1"),   ## uiOutput - gets the UI from the server
      uiOutput("data2"),
      uiOutput("data3")
    ),
    mainPanel()
  ))


server <- function(input, output){
  
  State <- c("NV", "NV","NV", "MD", "MD", "MD", "MD", "NY", "NY", "NY", "OH", "OH", "OH")
  County <- c("CLARK", "WASHOE", "EUREKA", "MONTGOMERY", "HOWARD", "BALTIMORE", "FREDERICK", "BRONX", "QUEENS", "WESTCHESTER", "FRANKLIN", "SUMMIT", "STARK" )
  City <- c("Las Vegas", "Reno", "Eureka", "Rockville", "Columbia", "Baltimore", "Thurmont", "Bronx", "Queens", "Yonkers", "Columbus", "Akron", "Canton")
  Rating<- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13)
  df <- data.frame(State, County, City, Rating, stringsAsFactors = F)
  
  ## renderUI - renders a UI element on the server
  ## used when the UI element is dynamic/dependant on data
  output$data1 <- renderUI({
    selectInput("data1", "Select State", choices = c(df$State))
  })
  
  ## input dependant on the choices in `data1`
  output$data2 <- renderUI({
    selectInput("data2", "Select County", choices = c(df$County[df$State == input$data1]))
  })
  
  output$data3 <- renderUI({
    selectInput("data3", "select City", choices = c(df$City[df$County == input$data2]))
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

You will notice the sample data is found in the `server` side code and binded together to form `df`.

But what if I didn't want to narrow my choice for each selection? Instead let's say I wanted to follow the following selection path: State = "MD", County = ALL, and City = ALL. While I would have the selection to choose just one or multiple selections, it would also include the selection to choose ALL.

Additionally, I would like to also include a dynamic table that is visible and adjusts itself based on the values selected. So if I were following the same selection path as listed above, it would return all the affiliated results for anything filed under State = "MD".

Whenever I try adding something like

```
DTOutput('table')
```

On the UI side and the following on the server side:

```
output$table <- renderDT(df,
                         options = list(
                           pageLength = 5
                         )
)
```

It just messes up the whole layout and also doesn't produce the table I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something to try out. You can use `updateSelectInput` to change your inputs and make them dependent. A separate `reactive` expression can filter your data based on your inputs. See if this gives you the intended behavior.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

State <- c("NV", "NV","NV", "MD", "MD", "MD", "MD", "NY", "NY", "NY", "OH", "OH", "OH")
County <- c("CLARK", "WASHOE", "EUREKA", "MONTGOMERY", "HOWARD", "BALTIMORE", "FREDERICK", "BRONX", "QUEENS", "WESTCHESTER", "FRANKLIN", "SUMMIT", "STARK" )
City <- c("Las Vegas", "Reno", "Eureka", "Rockville", "Columbia", "Baltimore", "Thurmont", "Bronx", "Queens", "Yonkers", "Columbus", "Akron", "Canton")
Rating<- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13)
df <- data.frame(State, County, City, Rating, stringsAsFactors = F)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Test Dashboard "),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("data1", "Select State", choices = c("All", unique(df$State))),
      selectInput("data2", "Select County", choices = NULL),
      selectInput("data3", "select City", choices = NULL)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      DTOutput("table")
    )
  ))

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  observeEvent(input$data1, {
    if (input$data1 != "All") {
      updateSelectInput(session, "data2", "Select County", choices = c("All", unique(df$County[df$State == input$data1])))
    } else {
      updateSelectInput(session, "data2", "Select County", choices = c("All", unique(df$County)))
    }
  }, priority = 2)
  
  observeEvent(c(input$data1, input$data2), {
    if (input$data2 != "All") {
      updateSelectInput(session, "data3", "Select City", choices = c("All", unique(df$City[df$County == input$data2])))
    } else {
      if (input$data1 != "All") {
        updateSelectInput(session, "data3", "Select City", choices = c("All", unique(df$City[df$State == input$data1])))
      } else {
        updateSelectInput(session, "data3", "Select City", choices = c("All", unique(df$City)))
      }
    }
  }, priority = 1)
  
  filtered_data <- reactive({
    temp_data <- df
    if (input$data1 != "All") {
      temp_data <- temp_data[temp_data$State == input$data1, ]
    }
    if (input$data2 != "All") {
      temp_data <- temp_data[temp_data$County == input$data2, ]
    }
    if (input$data3 != "All") {
      temp_data <- temp_data[temp_data$City == input$data3, ]
    }
    temp_data
  })
  
  output$table <- renderDT(
    filtered_data()
  )
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: this is very helpful, but what does the `priority = ...` stuff mean?

Comment: Also, what if I wanted to add a slider input that used the `Rating` metric?

Comment: For `priority` I was making sure the counties updated based on state, before the cities updated based on county. Here is more info on priority: An integer or numeric that controls the priority with which this observer should be executed. An observer with a given priority level will always execute sooner than all observers with a lower priority level. Positive, negative, and zero values are allowed.

Comment: You can add `sliderInput` after your other `selectInput` statements. Then, you can also filter your `temp_data` in the `reactive` expression based on the new rating input. I assume you didn't want to change the dropdowns based on rating. Does that help?

Comment: Let me know if you need any additional help (e.g., with the slider input).

Comment: Thanks for all this! Might need some help but I'll let you know!

Answer (score 1):

(Answered in reddit too)

1. This can be achieved by using `pickerInput()` from the `shinyWidgets` package

```
library(shinyWidgets)

output$data2 <- renderUI({
    pickerInput("data2", "Select County", 
                choices = c(df$County[df$State == input$data1]),
                options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE), multiple = T)
  })
```

2. This can be achieved saving your dataframe in a reactive and filtering acording to the options selected by user

```
data <- reactive({
    req(input$data1, input$data2, input$data3)
    df <- df %>%
      filter(State == input$data1) %>%
      filter(County %in% input$data2) %>% 
      filter(City %in% input$data3)
    df
  })
```

The hole app will look like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Test Dashboard "),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("data1"),   ## uiOutput - gets the UI from the server
      uiOutput("data2"),
      uiOutput("data3")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      DTOutput('table')
    )
  ))


server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  State <- c("NV", "NV","NV", "MD", "MD", "MD", "MD", "NY", "NY", "NY", "OH", "OH", "OH")
  County <- c("CLARK", "WASHOE", "EUREKA", "MONTGOMERY", "HOWARD", "BALTIMORE", "FREDERICK", "BRONX", "QUEENS", "WESTCHESTER", "FRANKLIN", "SUMMIT", "STARK" )
  City <- c("Las Vegas", "Reno", "Eureka", "Rockville", "Columbia", "Baltimore", "Thurmont", "Bronx", "Queens", "Yonkers", "Columbus", "Akron", "Canton")
  Rating<- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13)
  df <- data.frame(State, County, City, Rating, stringsAsFactors = F)
  
  ## renderUI - renders a UI element on the server
  ## used when the UI element is dynamic/dependant on data
  output$data1 <- renderUI({
    selectInput("data1", "Select State", choices = c(df$State))
  })
  
  ## input dependant on the choices in `data1`
  output$data2 <- renderUI({
    pickerInput("data2", "Select County", 
                choices = c(df$County[df$State == input$data1]),
                options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE), multiple = T)
  })
  
  output$data3 <- renderUI({
    pickerInput("data3", "select City", 
                choices = c(df$City[df$County %in% input$data2]),
                options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE), multiple = T)
  })
  
  data <- reactive({
    req(input$data1, input$data2, input$data3)
    df <- df %>%
      filter(State == input$data1) %>%
      filter(County %in% input$data2) %>% 
      filter(City %in% input$data3)
    df
  })
  
  output$table <- renderDT(
    data(), options = list(pageLength = 5)
  )
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Oh wow, I love this! Thank you!

Comment: Actually I do have a question. What if I didn't want all the input to be completely dependent on each other? For example, what if I wanted to make selecting county and city independent of one another? While they would both be dependent on what State is selected, say I wanted to skip County and go straight to City?

Comment: to further elaborate. Say I wanted to do just Nevada -> Las Vegas without having to pick County. Or if I wanted to do Nevada -> Clark without having to pick a city?